# convert .py to node-red flow

Tags: python, httprequest, node-red

Would anyone know how I can covert this Python http request with form data to a node red flow?

```
import requests

url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/read"
read_req = {"address": "12345:2",
        "object_type": "analogValue",
        "object_instance": "302"}

print(requests.post(url, read_req).text)
```

In node-red there is an http requests block:

[image]

But in node red it doesnt seem like there is an easy button for an http post for form data. Would anyone have any tips? Any tips with a javascript function would be greatly appreciated if I need to go to that extent.

[image]

Would I incorporate `msg.payload` javascript function like this into the http request node?
[image]

***UPDATED javascript function:***

```
msg.headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
};
msg.payload = {
    "address": "12345:2",
    "object_type": "analogValue",
    "object_instance": "302"
};
return msg;
```

Comment: https://discourse.nodered.org/t/how-to-send-a-post-request-with-content/15537

Comment: thanks for the link I think I need to figure out how to incorporate a javascript function `msg.payload` into this http requests block

Comment: In any case, this isn't really a python question - rather, how to add a payload to your http request node

Comment: Your new image looks correct to me, though, you might also want to update `msg.headers` with the Content-Type of application/json

Comment: Ok thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `msg.payload` in the inject node (or possibly in the function node between the inject and the http-request), not the HTTP-Request node.

The in screenshot you have included you have put what would be the content of a function node in the http-request node's description (this is purely somewhere to put some notes, not code).

The following flow should do what you want:

```
[{"id":"3a7d8d7b.32d6da","type":"inject","z":"628424e3.826234","name":"","topic":"","payload":"{\"address\":\"12345:2\",\"object_type\":\"analogValue\",\"object_instance\":\"302\"}","payloadType":"json","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":210,"y":440,"wires":[["ddc88307.6a405"]]},{"id":"5b9e61d9.4d0dc8","type":"debug","z":"628424e3.826234","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","x":580,"y":460,"wires":[]},{"id":"ddc88307.6a405","type":"http request","z":"628424e3.826234","name":"","method":"POST","ret":"txt","paytoqs":false,"url":"http://127.0.0.1:5000/read","tls":"","persist":false,"proxy":"","authType":"","x":400,"y":500,"wires":[["5b9e61d9.4d0dc8"]]}]
```